# XML attributes get sorted

Tags: python, xml, minidom

When I create a document using the minidom, attributes get sorted alphabetically in the element. Take this example from [here](http://developer.taboca.com/cases/en/creating_a_new_xml_document_with_python/):

```
from xml.dom import minidom

# New document
xml = minidom.Document()

# Creates user element
userElem = xml.createElement("user")

# Set attributes to user element
userElem.setAttribute("name", "Sergio Oliveira")
userElem.setAttribute("nickname", "seocam")
userElem.setAttribute("email", "seocam@taboca.com")
userElem.setAttribute("photo","seocam.png")

# Append user element in xml document
xml.appendChild(userElem)

# Print the xml code
print xml.toprettyxml()
```

The result is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<user email="seocam@taboca.com" name="Sergio Oliveira" nickname="seocam" photo="seocam.png"/>
```

Which is all very well if you wanted the attributes in email/name/nickname/photo order instead of name/nickname/email/photo order as they were created.

**How do you get the attributes to show up in the order you created them? Or, how do you control the order at all?**

Comment: Why do you want this? Attributes in XML have per definition no order (in contrast to elements). Is it just for beautification?

Comment: If I have an XSD that specifies the attributes in order C-B-A and I can wrie them only in order A-B-C, am I satisfying the XSD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html#namednodemap-objects), the order of attributes is arbitrary but consistent for the life of the DOM. This is common across DOM implementations. Sorry.